# Change connString daily in web.config automatically

Tags: web-config, connection-string

how would I change the connectionStrings automatically in the web.config file rotating daily from this:

```
    <add name="connString" connectionString="server=.\SERVER;database=TABLE1;Uid=USERID;Pwd=PASSWORD;" />
```

to this:

back to this:

etc...

Comment: to this:
<add name="connString" connectionString="server=.\SERVER;database=TABLE2;Uid=USERID;Pwd=PASSWORD;" />

Comment: back to this:
<add name="connString" connectionString="server=.\SERVER;database=TABLE1;Uid=USERID;Pwd=PASSWORD;" />

Comment: and repeat etc...